# Desktop application with custom uri schema, "Missing scheme" on token request

Tags: delphi, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm writing a desktop application in Delphi and trying to sync it with Google calendar (windows only, win 7 and newer). I've registered a custom uri schema in my system registry, so `eu.myapp:test` will run my program or pass a message to an already running instance of the program.

I've managed to get the first step of authentication going - I open the default browser, asking the user for permission to modify their calendars, I get the authentication code back into my software without a hitch. The oauth client is registered as an iOS app,

However when I try to request an actual token, the request is denied (400 - Bad request) with the following response body:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing scheme: eu.myapp",
    "error_uri": ""
}
```

My request body looks like this:

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=XXX&
client_id=YYY&
redirect_uri=eu.myapp&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#handlingtheresponse), I am supposed to include the redirect URI obtained from the API Console, but I found no such URI there. Found some older answers, but the developer console has apparently been changed since they were given so they are no longer relevant. What am I missing?

**Edit**: Added some more information
I built a simple nodejs server and put it up with a SSL certificate and nginx, so I could see what actually gets sent across. I then used both my app and the example C# app to send the token request to it and monitor the request body.
The only discernible difference was that delphi url encoded the code automatically (4%2Fhky... instead of 4/Fhky... for example). Other than that they seemed identical.

I also tried rewriting the app to listen to a localhost port but ended up with the same results. There is a delphi demo where they demonstrate the use of google api by using an embedded browser for the user to log in (and it works), but according to the api documentation, it's deprecated and will go away soon. Besides, it seems like I can manage the first redirect just fine, but getting the actual tokens fails.

Comment: if its a desktop application you should probably be just using a native credentials or Other. Not iOS.  then you can just send urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob as your redirect URI. It basically just means localhost.

Comment: It's the google's recommended approach for desktop apps - loopback ip or a custom URI schema and it actualy says that you should choose iOS as the Client type when using the schema approach on a desktop. Trying to get a C# sample to work at the moment, following their [demo](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/tree/master/OAuthUniversalApp)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/registering_an_application An installed application runs on a desktop computer or handheld device. You can create OAuth 2.0 credentials for Android, Chrome, iOS, and other installed applications.   Personally I prefer type other.   Try contacting the author of the demo sure they would be happy to help.   I haven't seen that one before so will probably not be much help.  Doesn't appear to use the Google .Net client library for C#.   So my samples wont be much help either.  Good luck

Comment: Try using `redirect_uri=eu.myapp:` instead. Note the trailing semicolon. Per [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986), a semicolon separates the scheme and path components of a URI.

Comment: @remylebeau
Tried that, didn't work. Then I changed the app a bit and made it listen on a custom port (http://localhost:4000). 
Same problem in both cases - I just get an "redirect_uri_mismatch" error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my error. I noticed that the parameters were getting encoded automatically by the delphi component responsible for making the requests. I manually encoded the redirect uri before setting it as a parameter on the token request. Then the component encoded it again, which caused it to be different to the url given on the code request, which caused the uri_mismatch error.

The uris also need to be identical on both requests, as even though the second request does not redirect, it still uses the redirect_uri as a validation parameter.